# Reiterating Sub TextBox1_Change() efficiently

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
Sub TextBox19_Change()
If Len(TextBox19.Value) = 4 Then TextBox19.Value = Mid(TextBox19.Value, 1, 3)
End Sub
Sub TextBox18_Change()
If Len(TextBox18.Value) = 4 Then TextBox18.Value = Mid(TextBox18.Value, 1, 3)
End Sub
Sub TextBox17_Change()
If Len(TextBox17.Value) = 4 Then TextBox17.Value = Mid(TextBox17.Value, 1, 3)
End Sub
Sub TextBox16_Change()
If Len(TextBox16.Value) = 4 Then TextBox16.Value = Mid(TextBox16.Value, 1, 3)
End Sub
```

How can I rephrase the above so that we don't have to duplicate the sub-routines for 100+ TextBoxes? There are more codes than just changing the textbox's value to its first 3 characters. I would appreciate a general efficient code. Thank you.

Edit: This isn't on a form. This is on PowerPoint Slides.

Comment: You could set the maxlength property?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't sure if you're using form textboxes here, but you could also use event sinking.

So create a class `clsCustomText` like so

```
Private WithEvents t As msforms.TextBox
Private Const lMaxLength As Long = 3

Public Sub Init(tIn As msforms.TextBox)
    Set t = tIn
End Sub

Private Sub t_Change()
    If Len(t.Value) > lMaxLength Then t.Value = Left(t.Value, lMaxLength)
End Sub
```

Then in a normal module, somewhere to hold them

```
Public colCustomTextboxes As Collection
```

and then in the form like so, i did mine on click, so i can test.  You'd need to move to initialize.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()

Dim c As Control
Dim t As clsCustomText

Set colCustomTextboxes = New Collection

For Each c In Me.Controls
    
    If TypeOf c Is msforms.TextBox Then
        Set t = New clsCustomText
        t.Init c
        colCustomTextboxes.Add t, c.Name
    End If
    
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: I would be having multiple ActiveX TextBoxes on my PPT Slide. Apologies for not mentioning that initially. How can I trigger an equivalent `UserForm_Click`? I am currently using `TextBoxXX_Change`